# How to get fulfillment # reference in invoice (header) in netsuite

Tags: javascript, scripting, netsuite, erp, invoice

Need to include a packing slip number (or shipment number) on the invoice belonging to the same shipment.

Comment: Can you add more details on the exact use case?

Comment: While creating invoice from sales order/ fulfillment, the invoice should display the fulfillment number related to that invoice.
Eg: SO has two fulfillment and each time invoice is generated from 'bill' button on fulfillment form, so each invoice should display its fulfillment number from where the invoice are created.